# PHP Path issue running backticks/exec()

Tags: java, php, macos

I'm trying to run a java jar file from the command line and within the the execution it gives a path. Withing this path their are spaces and this is causing the issue.

ie

```
foreach($paths as $path):
$f = `java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar /Folder/$path /ocr/output.txt`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
endforeach;
```

If you can see the space in between the Sub Folder name causes the issue.

By command line it would be (which works)

```
java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar /Folder/Sub\ Folder/filetoocr.pdf /ocr/output.txt
```

any suggestions how I can resolve this ??

Hope you can advise

Comment: Sorry I have now added a more real workld. As you can see path comes from a loop

Comment: I found the answer myself, Just adding quote around the path resolved the issue! ie, $f = `java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar '/Folder/$path' /ocr/output.txt`;

Answer (score 1):

Use [escapeshellarg()](http://docs.php.net/function.escapeshellarg):

> escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes *allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated **as a single safe argument***.

and maybe [escapeshellcmd()](http://docs.php.net/function.escapeshellcmd)

```
$cmd = sprintf(
  'java -jar %s %s %s',
  escapeshellarg('/OCR/ocr.jar'),
  escapeshellarg('/Folder/Sub Folder/filetoocr.pdf'),
  escapeshellarg('/ocr/output.txt')
);
echo 'Debug: cmd=', $cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = "java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar /Folder/Sub\\ Folder/filetoocr.pdf /ocr/output.txt";
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

or

```
$f = 'java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar "/Folder/Sub Folder/filetoocr.pdf" /ocr/output.txt';
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

add the same `\` in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes?

```
$f = `java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar '/Folder/Sub Folder/filetoocr.pdf' /ocr/output.txt`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `escape` the `space` even in the back ticks:

```
$f = `java -jar /OCR/ocr.jar /Folder/Sub\ Folder/filetoocr.pdf /ocr/output.txt`;
```